# Django: Make a query with restrictions on related models

Tags: django

Example Code

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    content = models.TextField()

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    content = models.TextField()


foo = Person.objects.create(name='foo')
bar = Person.objects.create(name='bar')

blog = Post.objects.create(author=foo,content='Random Blog 1')
blog2 = Post.objects.create(author=foo, content='Radom Blog 2')

c1 = Comment.objects.create(post=blog, author=foo, content='Comment on blog1')
c2 = Comment.objects.create(post=blog, author=bar, content='Bar comment on blog1')
c3 = Comment.objects.create(post=blog2, author=foo, content='Comment on blog2')
c4 = Comment.objects.create(post=blog2, author=bar, content='Bar comment on blog2')
```

How do I make a query that returns all Post's with author foo and only Comment's in each Post's comment_set are also made by foo.

Answer (score -1):

I would probably go with something like this:

```
    from django.db.models import Count, F

    Post.objects.filter(author=foo
        ).annotate(comment_count=Count('comment_set')
        ).filter(comment_set__author=foo #
        ).annotate(foo_comment_count=Count('comment_set')
        ).filter(foo_comment_count=F('comment_count')))
```

Another approach would be a subquery, to select posts that were commented by someone else then `foo` and then select all with PK not in that set.

Writing queries using Django's ORM is not very different from writing SQL queries. As a last resort, you can always write a [raw query](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/).